# Monty Hall Variation 2

Tags: probability, monty-hall

It is the same scenario as Monty Hall, except this time the contestant states which curtain he does not want, let's say C1. One of the remaining 2 curtains are opened to reveal a goat, say C2. To win the car, should the contestant now choose C3, or choose the curtain they didn't want originally?

Comment: The probability that the not wanted curtain contains the goat is $\frac{2}{3}$, so changing pays out like in the original version.

Comment: What have you tried?   Since the contestant is free to take (or to decline) the initial door (exactly as in the usual formulation), I don't actually see any difference at all.

Comment: the final decision is still between the two unopened curtains - is there a real difference between this and the original game?

Comment: What does it matter what he says? As long as this statement prevents from this door being opened and MH opens a door with a goat, this is the same problem.

Comment: The answer to this is different to the standard Monty Hall. By choosing a curtain not wanted, the contestant is actually choosinge 2 wanted curtains giving a 2/3 chance the car is behind one of those, & 1/3 chance the car is behind the unwanted curtain. In my scenario, C2 was eliminated by being revealed, so he now has a 2/3 chance the car is behind C3. Yes, this is the same equation as the original Monty Hall, but now the contestant's best chance is to stick with the rejection of C1 instead of changing as he should in the original Monty Hall. .

Comment: Not exactly, @PaulBarber . The final choice is still between the curtain originally selected or the unrevealed alternative; we just change which of these curtains "stay" and "switch" point to. The probabilities for wining when you make that final choice *of curtain* remain the same.

Comment: @PaulBarber sticking to the rejection of C1 is literally the same thing as switching to C3, or am i missing something?

Comment: Not sure if you know the answer to the original Monty Hall dilemia, if not, there is much on this site, and the Internet in general, explaining the probability. Very briefly the contestant always (2/3) has a better chance of selecting the correct curtain if they change their mind, as opposed to sticking with their original selection. The way I have worded my variaton on the original changes this to 2/3 chance if they stick.